# how can i log in as a particular user for postgres in terminal

Tags: postgresql, shell, git-bash

I am trying to create a different user for my postgres apart from the default.
I tried logging in as a different user using the code:

```
sudo -u username -i
```

in my git bash terminal but its giving me this reply:

```
$ sudo -u postgres -i
bash: sudo: command not found
```

how to successfully create another user using the git bash terminal to traverse postgres?

Comment: It's telling you that the program `sudo` is not a command that is found on that system. [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354928/bash-sudo-command-not-found)

Comment: Why `sudo` at all? `psql -U postgres` will start `psql` as the superuser. Then you'll be able to run `create user ...` to create  a new user.

Answer (score 1):

git bash doesn't come with sudo and apt-get which you would need to install sudo.  It's not a full linux/unix command system.  It's just the basics that you need for git commands.  I assume you're on a windows machine if you're using git bash, so sudo isn't available.

You can create a new role using psql and the permissions it needs.
`psql -U postgres -c "CREATE ROLE username LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEDB CREATEROLE;" mydb`